# LWR parameter estimation

Tags: lattice-crypto

I am trying to estimate parameters for LWR $(n,q,p)$ instance using the [LWE estimator](http://aleph.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNjcEKwjAQBe-F_kPoqYXYjZWkKHgQFPyLkOhii6mJyWrx782hiO84MPOcN9e6GohC2gHYkezrckdqfbzBZJwFN-MKE42TIR8hmhnOp8MRfqgNn6opiwdnxoXBcPZke9ZJxZlohRDbXknVSbGMMyXlpi-LhKTfGK1PWK-zr7O1NFHnz_ov2HwBPwsyhw==&lang=sage). My $q,p$ are $283,256$-bit prime numbers and I am trying to find required $n$ for 128 bit security.

For this, I need to know the $\alpha$ to be used in the estimator.

In the [paper](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Ecpeikert/pubs/prf-lattice.pdf) introducing LWR, the authors mention the analogous error rate is of the order of $\frac{1}{p}$.

What is the $\alpha$ I may need to use, is it $\alpha = \frac{1}{p}$ or is there more to that?